# Sent message or received message?

Tags: objective-c

1. As I known, `[self setDate:...]` mean `self` is receiver and `setDate:` is message. So which is the sender ?
2. I set a button with action `(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender`. I understood that this button is the targer and `buttonPressed` is the action. So which is can be `sender` ?

Answer (score 4):

> 1) As I known, `[self setDate:...]` mean `self` is receiver and `setDate:` is message. So which is the sender ?

The sender is the object—if any—that sent the message.

So which one is that?

1. You wrote the message in a statement.
2. You wrote that statement within a function, class method, or instance method.

   - If it was a function, then there is no object that was the sender.
   - If it was a class method, arguably the class is the sender (depending on how much you consider classes to be objects).
   - If it was an instance method, whichever object had that method called on it—i.e., received *that* message—is the sender of the `setDate:` message.

     For example, if you sent your `setDate:` message from an **instance method** named `buttonPressed:` in an NSWindowController subclass, then your window controller—the instance (object) that received the `buttonPressed:` message—is the object that sent the `setDate:` message.

Of course, if the receiver of the message is `self`, then you are sending the message to yourself, so you are both the receiver *and* the sender.

> 2) I set a button with action (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender. I understood that this button is the targer and buttonPressed is the action.

Nope! The button is not the target; the button *has* a target, which is another object. The target is the object that *receives* the action message.

Think of an archery target. The target doesn't send the arrow! It receives the arrow.

> So which is can be sender ?

The object that is referred to by the `sender` variable generally is the object that sent the message.

Usually, it is a control (such as a button) or menu item: when pressed, the control or menu item sends its action message to its target, passing itself (the control or menu item) as the “sender”.

So your button would send a message to its target, the message being whichever one is set as the button's action, and because it's sending the message, it would pass itself as the `sender`.

The only reason to look at the `sender` at all is to examine the sender's `tag` or `representedObject`. An action method is about the only kind of method that may need to care at all about the sender (which is why it has this argument), and even then, usually not.

Answer (score 0):

The sender is the object preforming the task....assuming your example (IBAction)buttonPressed:

If you are pressing a button, that button is doing the sending of whatever code follows. See my example

```
- (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender {
UIButton *pushedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
[button setTitle:@"Press me to Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, `self` is the receiver of the message and `setDate:` is the message (the method call). There is no "sender". What do you mean by "sender" anyway?

2) In code, setting up the button to call the `buttonPressed:` method is done like this:

```
[someButton addTarget:someTarget action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

`someTarget` is typically `self`. The "target" is the object that has the "action" method. The method looks like:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
}
```

The "someButton" is the "sender" since it is the button that had the event.

Comment: 1) `sender` mean which sent the message ?

Comment: If that's what you mean then the object that makes the call would be considered the "sender".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, In objective- c messaging  system don't have any formal notion of "sender".

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender.

  Here sender is just ordinary method argument ,not a part of objective c messaging system.Just a way argument is named in Appkit or UIKIt.
- [self setDate:...]
  here "self" is receiver and setDate: is message.

Please note : in ordinary speech "sending a message" implies three thing: sender,receiver and message.Where sender is function or block of  code that contain message. But that analogy is not applicable for objective c.